# Linq query string array inside List of strings

Tags: c#, list, linq

Hey all I am trying to query for the string number thats in the first position inside my List:

```
List<string[]> idMainDescriptionIcon = new List<string[]>(){
   //              [ID]       [Main]               [Description]               "XX[d=day or n=night]"
   new string[4] { "200", "Thunderstorm",  "thunderstorm with light rain",     "11" },
   new string[4] { "201", "Thunderstorm",  "thunderstorm with rain",           "11" },
   new string[4] { "202", "Thunderstorm",  "thunderstorm with heavy rain",     "11" },
   new string[4] { "210", "Thunderstorm",  "light thunderstorm",               "11" },
   new string[4] { "211", "Thunderstorm",  "thunderstorm",                     "11" }
};
```

And the Linq I am using:

```
List<string> d = idMainDescriptionIcon[0][0]
  .Where(x => x.StartsWith("202"))
  .Select(x => x)
  .ToList();
```

I am getting an error on the `idMainDescriptionIcon[0][0]` stating:

> Error CS1061  'char' does not contain a definition for 'StartsWith' and
> no accessible extension method 'StartsWith' accepting a first argument
> of type 'char' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
> assembly reference?)

The D should have the values of `"202", "Thunderstorm", "thunderstorm with heavy rain", "11"`.

And this is where I am stuck at. Not sure how to go about fixing this error?

**UPDATE #1**

When removing the [0][0] and replacing it with just one [0] this is the return I get:

[image]

Comment: `idMainDescriptionIcon[0][0]` got one too many [0].

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jawad. I have updated my OP to show what I get when only using the one [0] instead of [0][0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is `idMainDescriptionIcon[0][0]`, which is referring to a single string here. Iterating over it would be iterating over characters in the string, which is why you get the error `'char' does not contain a definition for 'StartsWith'`

What you would need is the following

```
var d = idMainDescriptionIcon
  .Where(x => x[0].StartsWith("202"))
  .SelectMany(x => x)
  .ToList();
```

You need to query the entire `idMainDescriptionIcon` such that the first element of the inner array starts with "202".

Alternatively,

```
var d = idMainDescriptionIcon
  .FirstOrDefault(x => x[0].StartsWith("202"))
  .ToList();
```

Output

[image]

Comment: That did the trick Anu! It works as it should now :)

Comment: You may also have been right about `SelectMany()`, where the op wants a collection of strings directly, though that is a slightly unusual way to request the data.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Any particular reason to prefer `x[0]` over `First()` in your Edit?

Comment: The combination of `StartsWith()` in the `Where()` along with `SelectMany()` could result in unexpected output depending on what @StealthRT is attempting. Replacing `Where()` with `FirstOrDefault()` might be better.

Comment: @Corey Done, Thanks for the suggestion